# Lognormal random variable times a constant

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X$ is a random variable lognormally distributed, then can we say that $Y=cX$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$ is lognormal too?
I think that if $c$ is large enough the central limit theorem applies and $Y$ will be normal. But I guess for reasonable values of $c$ (for example $c<30$) maybe it is not true.

Mostly I'm thinking in the case when we need to change the units of $X$. Does it changing the units of a quantity change also its distribution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The CLT concerns the (suitably transformed) sum of many independent variables, not a variable multiple by a large constant. As zoli shows below, $cX$ will be log-normal for any $c>0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $X$ is a [log-normal random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Notation) then it can be written as

$$X=e^{\mu+\sigma Z}$$
where $Z$ is of standard normal distribution.

Then, for a $c>0$

$$cX=ce^{\mu+\sigma Z}=e^{\ln(c)}e^{\mu+\sigma Z}=e^{\mu+\ln(c)+\sigma Z}=e^{\mu'+\sigma Z}.$$

So, $cX$ is still log-normal. ($c$ cannot be negative because a negative random variable cannot be of log-normal. The definition of the log-normal distribution contains the need to take the logarithm of $X$.)

I don't understand what does this have to do with the central limit theorem. $c$ is not the size of a sample; it is a scaling factor.

Comment: Thank for the answer. About the CLT what I meant is $cX=X+X+X+X...$ so although they are not independent random variables, somehow $cX$ approximates a normal for big enough $c$.

Comment: @Ambesh: I suspected that. (Sorry for being obnoxiously pseudo ignorant.)  But independence is very importanant in the case of the central limit theorem. Just think of the sum of random variables that can be negative and positive (independently) ; they would sort of neutralize each other as opposed to $X+X+\cdots$ in which case adding $X$ to itself just augments what is already in $X$.

Comment: +1 - in effect $\log(c)$ is a location shift for the underlying normal distribution